# Evitar que se repitan numeros generados para Loteria

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, random

les cuento que estoy terminando de afinar un proyecto y dentro del mismo tengo un generador de numeros al azar realizado en javascript, pero para que quede 10 puntos me guatria que los numeros que genera no se repitan , ya que muchas veces, de los numeros que imprime, alguno se repite, tengo dividido el panel con dos sectores, uno que genera 6 numeros del 0 al 41, y otro que genera 2 numeros del 0 al 9, solo me faltaria el detalle de la no repeticion, a continuacion les muestro el codigo a ver si alguno me puede dar una mano.

```js
 //CREATES A FUNCTION THAT CREATES A RANDOM NUMBER AND PUTS IT IN THE CIRCLE
 function random(){
  //SELECT THE FIVE CIRCLES ON THE PAGE
  var one= document.getElementById('one');
  var two= document.getElementById('two');
  var three= document.getElementById('three');
  var four= document.getElementById('four');
  var five= document.getElementById('five');
  var six= document.getElementById('six');
  var seven= document.getElementById('seven');
  var eight= document.getElementById('eight');

  //CREATE A RANDOM NUMBER FOR EACH OF THE CIRCLES
  var a = Math.floor(Math.random()*41);
  var b = Math.floor(Math.random()*41);
  var c = Math.floor(Math.random()*41);
  var d = Math.floor(Math.random()*41);
  var e = Math.floor(Math.random()*41);
  var f = Math.floor(Math.random()*41);
  var g = Math.floor(Math.random()*9);
  var h = Math.floor(Math.random()*9);
  
  //PUT RANDOM NUMBERS TO EACH OF THE CIRCLES
  one.textContent = a;
  two.textContent = b;
  three.textContent = c;
  four.textContent = d;
  five.textContent = e;
    six.textContent = f;
  seven.textContent = g;
  eight.textContent = h;
  
  //THIS ONE IS DIFFERENT BECAUSE THE CIRCLE IS RED
  seven.style.color = 'red';
  seven.textContent = g;
  eight.style.color = 'red';
  eight.textContent = h;

 }
```

```css
body{
  background: #222;
} 
.container{
 height: 520px;
 width: 340px;
 background: #45A5C7;
 margin: 60px auto;
 padding: 1px 10px;
 }
 .ball{
  margin:1px;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  height: 65px;
  width: 65px;
  background: white; 
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  left: -1%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
 }
 .statement , .center{
  text-transform: uppercase;
 }
 .center{
  text-align: center;
 } 
 .numbers{
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;

 }
 button{
 position: relative;
 left: 50%;
 }
 #num7{
 background: yellow;
 }
  #num8{
 background: yellow;
 }
 .c{
  background: white;
  color: black;
 }
 .state{
  clear: both;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  right: 10%;
  top: 1%;
 }
 .statement{
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  left: 1%;
  top: 5%;
  
}
 #logo{
  position: relative;
  top: 5%;
 }
 .center{
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
 }
 button{
  position: relative;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 45%;
 }
 .c{
  font-size: 2em;
 }
```

```html
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Generar numeros para LotoPlus</title>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div id="logo">
   <div class="ball">L</div>
   <div class="ball">a</div>
   <div class="ball">R</div>
   <div class="ball">e</div>
   <div class="ball">a</div>
   <div class="ball c">l</div>
  </div>
  <div class="state">Ag. Oficial 0479</div>
  <p class="statement">Perdiste tus números? No sabes cuales jugar? <br>No te preocupes! <br> PowerBall de La Real te Ayuda! <br> Vamos por los MILLONES.</p>
  <p class="center">Jugate con estos!</p>
  <div class="numbers">
   <div class="row">
    <div id="num1" class="ball col-md-2"><span id="one"></span></div>
    <div id="num2" class="ball col-md-2"><span id="two"></span></div>
    <div id="num3" class="ball col-md-2"><span id="three"></span></div>
    <div id="num4" class="ball col-md-2"><span id="four"></span></div>
    <div id="num5" class="ball col-md-2"><span id="five"></span></div>
    <div id="num6" class="ball col-md-2"><span id="six"></span></div>
    <div id="num7" class="ball col-md-2"><span id="seven"></span></div>
    <div id="num8" class="ball col-md-2"><span id="eight"></span></div>
   </div>
  </div>


 </div>
 <button onclick="random()">A GANAR!</button>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Para comprobar que no se repiten los números puedes utilizar un array auxiliar y hacer la función de random para obtener el número.

Se comprueba que el número no está ya en el array. En caso de que esté se vuelve a aplicar la función random para obtener otro número y así hasta llenar un array de longitud 6, es decir, 6 números distintos, como parece que querías hacer en tu problema.

```
var numeros = []
while( numeros.length < 6 ){
    let numero = Math.floor(Math.random()*41);
    if (!numeros.includes(numero)){
      numeros.push(numero);
    }
}
```

Para juntarlo con tu código podrías hacer esto:

```
var a = numeros[0];
var b = numeros[1];
var c = numeros[2];
var d = numeros[3];
var e = numeros[4];
var f = numeros[5];
```

Comment: hola Gonzalo, gracias ahora pruebo como va...

Comment: No hay caso che, algo seguro estoy haciendo mal ... no soy un gran dominador de codigos, donde deberia color el codigo que me pasate? y deberia agregarle algun dato para relacionarlo con el codigo que ya tengo ?

Comment: Ya está editado, de una forma más larga para entenderlo mejor @porloscerrosΨ